# How to mock an imported array and test the using Function

Tags: javascript, mocking, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I'm exporting an array:

```
//constants.js
export const myarray = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'];

//checkFunction.js
import myarray from ./constants

function check(value) {
    return myarray.includes(value);
}
```

I want to be able to mock the array in my testing suite so that I can control its values for different tests.
My problem is, using Mocha & Sinon, how do I test the function `check()` and mock the imported array `myarray`.
If I create a stub for `check()` how do I get it to consume the mocked `myarray`?

```
sinon.stub(checkFunction, 'checkFunction')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing the `check` function, you should NOT stub it. Like your said, you should mock the `myarray` in test cases. You could mutate the value of `myarray` before `require`/`import` the `checkFunction.js` module. Make sure to clear the module cache before running each test case, so that subsequent imports of the `constants` module will give you a fresh `myarray`, not the mutated one.

E.g.

`constants.js`:

```js
export const myarray = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'];
```

`checkFunction.js`:

```js
import { myarray } from './constants';

export function check(value) {
  console.log('myarray: ', myarray);
  return myarray.includes(value);
}
```

`checkFunction.test.js`:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('72411318', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./checkFunction')];
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./constants')];
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const { myarray } = require('./constants');
    myarray.splice(0, myarray.length);
    myarray.push('beef', 'lobster');
    const { check } = require('./checkFunction');
    expect(check('apples')).to.be.false;
  });

  it('should pass 2', () => {
    const { check } = require('./checkFunction');
    expect(check('apples')).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  72411318
myarray:  [ 'beef', 'lobster' ]
    ✓ should pass (194ms)
myarray:  [ 'apples', 'oranges', 'pears' ]
    ✓ should pass 2


  2 passing (204ms)
```

Comment: Thank you @slideshowp2. This works as you suggested. I would never have thought of using this option `delete require.cache[require.resolve(' ')]` 
It's not something I see documented with the test suite I'm using so would never have considered it.